# My data is posted 2 times on my jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In the dialog form below, I have 2 buttons: Save & Cancel. When user double-click save button, my data is posted 2 times. How can I avoid it?

```
$(this).dialog({
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            title: "Edit",
            close: function () { $(this).dialog('destroy').remove(); },
            buttons: {
                "Save": function () {
                    // Manually submit the form
                    var form = $('form', this);
                    $(form).submit();                        
                },
                "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog('destroy').remove(); }
            }
        });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old problem. One thing that you could do is

```
var submitted = false;
$(this).dialog({
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        title: "Edit",
        close: function () { $(this).dialog('destroy').remove(); },
        buttons: {
            "Save": function () {
                // Manually submit the form
                if(!submitted){
                    submitted = true;
                    var form = $('form', this);
                    $(form).submit();                        
                }
            },
            "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog('destroy').remove(); }
        }
    });
```